# Lutris doesn't work when I try to install it

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
$ sudo apt install lutris
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 lutris : Depends: python3-evdev but it is not installable
          Depends: cabextract but it is not installable
          Depends: fluid-soundfont-gs but it is not installable
          Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable
          Recommends: gvfs-backends
          Recommends: libwine-development but it is not installable
          Recommends: winetricks but it is not installable
          Recommends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the message that it gives me.
I already tried to upgrade my system.

```
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Where did you get `lutris` from since it's not in the default repos for 18.04?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy lutris mesa-utils`?

Comment: delpepito@delpepito:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan

Comment: delpepito@delpepito:~$ apt-cache policy lutris mesa-utils
lutris:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.5
  Version table:
     0.5.5 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
mesa-utils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: It seems you have deleted/messed sources.list. Try restoring default repositories from Software and Updates application. Once done, run `sudo apt update; sudo apt install lutris`. If you still encounter errors, ping me in comments using @Kulfy so that I won't miss any comment like I missed the last one.

Comment: How do i restore it sorry i'm a beginner ? @Kulfy

Comment: I did some research on internet about restoring software i found this command delpepito@delpepito:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
but it returns me that E: Unable to locate package software-properties-gtk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but I found that everything works if you enable *Canonical-supported free and open software (main)* in the Software & Updates app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Lutris after enable all checkbox in **Software & Updates** as in the attached figure below.

- Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)
- Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)
- Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)
- Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)

[image: Software & Updates - img]

Comment: Hello. The OP states the error is unmet dependencies. You can not solve that issue this way. They need to install the missing files one at a time. Your answer does not fix unmet dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to solve this by installing build-essential following 
https://railsblogs.rohityadav.in/2019/06/e-package-aptitude-has-no-installation.html

1. follow the steps in the link until the last(install aptitude)
2. restart
3. apt-get update followed by apt-get upgrade followed by apt-get dist-upgrade
4. and then sudo apt-get install --fix-missing lutris

there is no need to use aptitude

Comment: Installing build-essential will not help as it seems missing dependencies.

Comment: By posting a link here and asking to follow steps in it, the answer is kind of incomplete... I took a look at the link. You could just put down the steps here thus fully keeping your provided solution here.